# How to pass properties from interface in Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, components

Ho to implement interface in component?
Is it possible to avoid the `@input` part and do it on different way?

Interface:

```
export default interface Example {
  title: string;
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './Example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Example.scss'],
})

export default class Example{
  @Input() title: any;
}
```

Comment: What's you aim to do? @Input is a way of sharing data between components , Interfaces are used for typing your data ,

Comment: Can you share your code please !

Comment: I updated the answer. So if i am adding new prop in the interface i need to add it too in the component file. How to reduce that?

Comment: you can use the '?' operator  (optional parameter ) with your interfaces to add more flexibility to your code! it will make them optional and not required to be implemented

Comment: ok, so i guess there is no other way to pass them like on React props

Comment: You already have a class.. why also have an interface? A class already acts as an interface..

Comment: But if it will be used only for data type definition , I think the recommended way is using interfaces instead of class!

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you need.. but you can create an interface like MyExample and then use an implements on your class like class Example implements MyExample..?

Comment: I think he needs to type the title property title : Example, but it's not necessary to have all the fields defined!

Comment: @Rebai I need all the fields, but i am wondering if there is a way where i can reduce the steps for writing the code. so i wont go like `@input title: string` an than `@input name: string`...

Comment: @Input myObject: Interface;

Comment: @Rebai thank you ill try this now

Comment: An interface does not contain implementation. The interface is more like a plan for a implementation. If you dont want to implement the input in the component, you need to extend an abstract base class. the abstract base class can contain the "prepared" implementations.